# $_GET command not working

Tags: php, yii

I have an issue.

```
echo CHtml::button('Sell It', array('submit' => array('mobile/create', array('id'=>$data->id))));
```

and after doing the above operation i'm getting the url to be

```
http://localhost/abhimir-mobile-d28927ecb74b/index.php/mobile/create?0%5Bid%5D=1
```

now im using the `$_GET['id']` in the view of another controller.....how do i pass a variable from view of one contoller to view of another?

Comment: why did you and Abhinav ask essentially the same question? i am flagging this.

Comment: I'm assuming this is partly an English language issue but it does seem like two people are working on the same thing just note that there are two issues. It also doesn't help to offer generic advice if you don't understand the framework issue.

Comment: @elchief If it was your flag I just invalidated, here's a tip for the future: *write what you know*. Did you know there are 28 users with the name Abhinav? Don't make moderators hunt for the information you already have, give it to us. If it wasn't your flag, this comment is for whoever *did* flag this question and left no text at all.

Answer (score 6):

`create?id=1` and `create?0%5Bid%5D=1` are not the same, try `$_GET['0[id]']` or `var_dump($_GET)`;

Answer (score 4):

**$_GET is not a command**, it's an [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)! Once you've unserstood that, you should be able to understand your problem.

If you have a problem with getting values from an array, always look into your array with:

- print_r(array) or
- var_dump(array) or
- even better the debugger!

Answer (score 2):

The array for the path/route + data is a single array, it should be like this:

```
echo CHtml::button('Sell It', array('submit' => array('mobile/create','id'=>1)));
```

The way you have it is mangling the name/value pairs which is why it looks like that.